# How to navigate to a folder's default page (.razor) in Blazor Server app?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, razor-components

In my blazor app I have a hierarchy of razor component (pages) folders. Each folder represents a data model and includes 4 .razor pages.

```
Contacts
     List.razor
     View.razor
     Edit.razor
     Create.razor
Accounts
     List.razor
     View.razor
     Edit.razor
     Create.razor
```

etc.

URLs for these pages:

```
/contacts/list
/contacts/view
/contacts/edit
/contacts/create
/accounts/list
/accounts/view
/accounts/edit
/accounts/create
```

My goal is when I type in browser `/contacts` it should be routed to a default page in that folder, which is `/contacts/list`
Or if I type `/accounts`, it must route to `/accounts/list`

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a second `@page` directive on the page you want to be the canonical top-level.

```
@page "/contacts/list"
@page "/contacts"
```

If you absolutely must *redirect* from `/contacts` to `/contacts/list` you can use `NavigationManager` on a `/contacts` page to redirect to the list page.

Comment: There is no such a page as "contacts", but a folder "Contacts". Do you mean that I have to create a dummy page inside of the Contacts folder with a page directive `@page "/contacts"` and then on initialization of the page redirect to `/contacts/list` with NavigationManager?

Comment: Yep, you’ve got it. If you cannot use two page directives on the /lists page then that’s the way to go (pending the other answer not being an unintended feature.)

Comment: @ElshadShabanov just to clarify, all you have to do is add the two rows in this answer to get what you are asking. You can add as many page directives as you like (i guess?) to match different routes that will display your `lists` page. Only do the redirect thing if you *really have to*...